# Retrieving Worker Index from Asynchronous Function Evaluation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm attempting to carry out an iterative algorithm in MATLAB using parallel processing. There exists multiple iterative series that are updated by individual, iterative workers. These workers then send their latest iteration to a [`DataQueue`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/send.html) on an analytics worker. The analytics worker pulls the next update from the queue and updates the analytics accordingly. However, the analytics cannot be updated properly unless the analytics worker knows from which iterative worker the update has been passed.

The following attempt has been made to report an identifier for the worker that is carrying out the asynchronous function evaluation:

```
for j = 1:20
   L(j) = parfeval(gcp, @() labindex, 1);
end

for j = 1:20
   [~,idx] = fetchNext(L)
end

function index = labindex()
   index = labindex
end
```

This code reports an `idx` value of `1` for all evaluations. Is this the correct way of getting the identifier of the worker that is handling the function evaluation? Is there another property that I should be using? Is there some way to create a unique identifier for the worker that is completing the work such that the analytics worker knows which worker computed the next iteration in the series?

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for Documentation about labindex in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labindex.html)

Labindex will return the index of the worker which is unique to that particular worker only if you use an spmd block. spmd blocks give you full control over individual workers. spmd blocks are so convenient that they even help you transfer data between workers.

[Click here for Documentation about spmd in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html)

I hope this helped.